# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' Invocation of init method No identifier specified for entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, pom.xml

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.example.demo.entities.courses.Course

**Courses Class**

```
package com.example.demo.entities.courses;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import com.example.demo.entities.BaseEntities;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Course extends BaseEntities {
    
@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name="title", length=100)
@Size(max=100, message ="Title must be less than 100 charachters")

private String title;

//public String getTitle() {
//  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  return null;
//}

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name="description", length=1000)
@Size(max=1000, message ="Title must be less than 1000 charachters")

private String description;


@NotNull(message ="Price must not be null")
@DecimalMin("1.00")
private BigDecimal price;
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application pro**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iAcademy?  createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing id field in your entity

```
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")<---- this "id" value should match the id from your database
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
```

Make sure that import is `javax.persistence.Id`

Comment: if you look in my class course I extended from base entity class this class has id and I put the annotation @id with this javax.persistence.Id so still same error

Comment: Does your COURSE table, have id field in your database? If it does your entity should as well. Try to add it to your course entity, not in your BaseEntities

Answer (score 0):

There is no field having `@Id` annotation defined in your entity class.
The field annotated with `@Id` is the **primary key** of your SQL table.

Here is the correct code -

```
package com.example.demo.entities.courses;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import com.example.demo.entities.BaseEntities;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Course extends BaseEntities {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="course_id")
private Integer courseId
    
@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name="title", length=100)
@Size(max=100, message ="Title must be less than 100 charachters")

private String title;

//public String getTitle() {
//  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  return null;
//}

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name="description", length=1000)
@Size(max=1000, message ="Title must be less than 1000 charachters")

private String description;


@NotNull(message ="Price must not be null")
@DecimalMin("1.00")
private BigDecimal price;
}
```

Comment: if you look in my class course I extended from base entity class this class has id and I put the annotation @id with this javax.persistence.Id so still same error